# Page Inflator Doesn't work inside onPageChangeListener()

Tags: android

I use a `layout inflater` inside an array adapter. I use the `layout inflater` in the `getView` method on a view pager and it works fine. I use the same exact code inside an `onPageChangeListner` and the layout inflator does not work. I know this code is being executed, however android isn't letting me dynamically update the layout. What could possibly be the reason for this?

Comment: plese show us the code.

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working, will bump it to the top of the active queue.